# Why java cannot reconcile the `?` generic type from different sources

Tags: java, generics

I have a (as I understand) monad in place made for specific domain, which acts as a combination of Either/Try and an action for rest endpoint call. It's a class with a single type generic parameter for it's contained value. Because some functions are only written for side effect and don't care for return value, I commonly annotated their return simply as `MyMonadThing<?>`. However, such pattern gives me issue when trying to fork logic at some places. I won't show the monad class, but here is example using lists that illustrates the problem

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    map(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3), t -> {
        return t == 2? foo() : bar();
    });
}

static <T, NewT> List<NewT> map(List<T> lst, Function<T, List<NewT>> fn) {
    return lst.stream().flatMap(t -> fn.apply(t).stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

static List<?> foo() {
    return Arrays.asList("foo");
}

static List<?> bar() {
    return Arrays.asList("bar");
}
```

This won't compile because of ternary.

```
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<capture#2-of ?> to 
 List<Object>
```

I can fix this by casting (ie `return (List<?>) (t == 2? foo() : bar());`) but that's just odd. Suppose java did allow this to run, and the result in main would be simply of type `List<?>` -- under what circumstances could this result in an actual error due to unsound type system?

Comment: The ternary must return a type common to both branches. Since nothing is known about `?` the common type is `Object`. So Java attempts `List<Object>` but a `List<?>` is **not** a `List<Object>`, hence it does not work. It could be a list of cats, that do not support adding dogs to it, but `List<Object>` would allow that. Generics in Java are invariant, not covariant. See `condition ? "hello" : 5` which returns `Object` since that is the only type `String` and `Integer` (autoboxed) have in common.

Comment: @Zabuzard but oddly it work if `return t == 2? foo() : bar();` is packed into its own method with `List<?>` as a return type.

Comment: Because then the return type is `List<?>` and not `List<Object>`. If you change the return type of your method to `List<Object>` you get the same issue.

Comment: @Zabuzard `Since nothing is known about ? the common type is Object. So Java attempts List<Object>`  why is java forced to decide this immediately? Why cannot it propagate it simply as List<?> further?

Comment: You have to ask the Java language designers for that - thats how the language works.